# random number with range and multiplier in java

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to generate a random number within a range, and of a specific multiple. My example would be within the range of 60 - 500, and only multiples of 5, e.g. 60, 65, 70 -> 500

I'm trying to use random.nextInt(), but I can either get the range to work, or the multiplier, but not both.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Like, `nextInt(0, 10) * 5`?

Comment: Could you show the code that didn't work, together with what it should have done?

Comment: Sounds like an answer, tobias.

Answer (score 3):

I'd work my way backwards - generate a random number and **then** multiply it by the multiple you want:

```
int multiple = 5;
int rangeStart = 60;
int rangeEnd = 500;

int calcRangeStart = rangeStart / multiple;
int calcRangeEnd = rangeEnd / multiple;

int random = new Random().nextInt(calcRangeStart, calcRangeEnd) * multiple;
```

Comment: you need to add `1` to the end of the range - it's exclusive.

Comment: Thanks heaps Mureinik, great resolution. It seems really clear when you do it that way, no idea why my code was getting so convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

First work out the number of possible values for your random number, which is

```
((500-60)/5 + 1) or
((505-60)/5)
```

using integer division.  Using this value as an argument to Random.nextInt will give you values starting from 0.  So you just need to multiply by 5 and add 60 to get values in your desired range

```
Random random = new Random();
(random.nextInt((505-60)/5) * 5 + 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your from-to and multiply numbers as ints and then generate them like this:

```
int from = 60, to = 500, multi = 5;
Random rand = new Random();
int n = multi*(Math.round(rand.nextInt((to+multi-from))+from)/multi);
```

This code will generate numbers from 60 to 500 in multiplies of 5 only.

Comment: I have no idea how this works but it does :) I'm going to have to sit down and break out that line of code to better understand it. Thanks for the suggestion Aradmey!

Answer (score 0):

```
int seed = 5;
Random random = new Random();
int inf = 12;
int sup = 100;
int number = random.nextInt((sup-inf)+1) + inf;
number *= seed;
```